# i don't understand some syntax of js "${method_name}"

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers

Here is the code i didn't understand the some syntax like `${method_name}` what we are doing by passing the method name to curly braces.

```
  global._jsname.prototype.createEELayer = function (ftRule) {
  if (this.EELayer) { return; }
  var that = this;
  var myStyle = new OpenLayers.Style ({
  externalGraphic : 'images/man.png',
  graphicOpacity : "${opac}",
  cursor : "pointer",
  graphicWidth : "20px",
  label:"${labelNumber}",
  graphicHeight : "20px",
  graphicYOffset : -9,
  graphicXOffset : -12,
  graphicTitle: "Drag me to move along the route"
 },
{ context :{ 
opac : function (feature) { 
  if (feature.editOpacity) {
    return feature.editOpacity;
  } else {
    return "1.0";
  }
}
,labelNumber : function (feature) {
  var labelNo = feature.data.stopN;
  return labelNo;
}
} 
});

this.EELayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("EELayer",{ 
styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
  "default" : myStyle,
  "onSelect":myStyle
}), 
isBaseLayer : false
});
this.mbox.map.addLayer(this.EELayer);
}
```

One more thing i didn't get is why method name (labelNumbber) is given in `${labelNumber}`.

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
....
label:"${labelNumber}",

....
```

is defining a property named `label` which is assigned a **`string`**. So, what the meaning of the term "${labelNumber}" in this string is, is up to the programs further logic.

Actually, within these few lines, it has no functionality, as it is only a literal and the property is not used in here.

Comment: i debugged it and found that the method `labelNumber` is been called after few intervals may be 1.5sec.so it's done by OpenLayer but i didn't know when n where this method is been called.

Comment: This could be probably new ES6 Syntax, see this article (in German only, but googling for ECMA Script 6 may help also) http://ct.de/y376 - this would replace the `${labelNumber}` with the current value and thus creating a String with the name ?

Answer (score -1):

This is the usuall way to pass dinamic variable from **PHP** to html/js `{$method_name}`.
So this variables/names probably come from other part of your code that reuse the curent file as template.

Comment: This is __no__ PHP variable, mind the syntax: here `${labelNumber}`, php `{$labelNumber}`

Answer (score -1):

maybe a spring MVC Languange
I use it often

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/

seen  number 4, it can be used in js also